Job Conditions in Azure Pipelines
In my yaml pipeline I have multiple jobs which are dependent on each other. However in one of the jobs when I define the condition, I am getting the following error:
Unexpected symbol: ')'. Located at position 53 within expression: and(not(or(failed('Unittests'), canceled('Unittests'))), not(canceled('Check_Requirements'))). For more help, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=842996

This is how I defined the job which is showing the error:
  - job: Security_Check
displayName: "Security Check"
dependsOn:
  - Check_Requirements
  - Unittests
condition: and(not(or(failed('Unittests'), canceled('Unittests'))), not(canceled('Check_Requirements')))
pool:
  name: "Basic_Pool_Ubuntu"
variables:
  - name: foundVuls
    value: $[ dependencies.Check_Requirements.outputs['CheckVuls.foundVul'] ]
  - name: Artifact.Folder
    value: "artifacts"

I want the Job to run when the Job 'Unittests' has not failed or cancelled and the job 'Check_Requirement' has not failed.
Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here. I tried multiple ways to define this condition but always got the "Unexpected symbol: ')'" Error

Please edit your question and paste the code as text, not as an image.

From your yaml sample, the condition expression is too complicated. I suggest you simplify the content of the condition. You can refer to the answer to modify the condition expression and check if it can work.

Based on your YAML sample, I can reproduce the same issue.


I want the Job to run when the Job 'Unittests' has not failed or cancelled and the job 'Check_Requirement' has not failed.

To meet your requirement, you can use the following condition:
condition: and(notIn(dependencies.Unittests.result, 'failed', 'canceled'), ne(dependencies.Check_Requirements.result, 'canceled'))

YAML Sample:
- job: Security_Check
  displayName: "Security Check"
  dependsOn:
    - Check_Requirements
    - Unittests
  condition: and(notIn(dependencies.Unittests.result, 'failed', 'canceled'), ne(dependencies.Check_Requirements.result, 'canceled'))
  pool:
    name: "Basic_Pool_Ubuntu"
  variables:
    - name: foundVuls
      value: $[ dependencies.Check_Requirements.outputs['CheckVuls.foundVul'] ]
    - name: Artifact.Folder
      value: "artifacts"

